# Minimal code, shorten expression

Tags: java, operators, comparator

Following parameters are given:

```
boolean a = true ;
boolean b = false ;
boolean c = true ;
```

I want to have minimal code of this version:

```
if ( ( a && ! b) || ( ! a && b) ) {
    z1 += 99 ;
}

if (a ^ b) {
    z1 += 19 ;
}

if ( ( a && b) || ( ! a && ! b) ) {
    z1 += 118;
}
```

What needs to be modified?

Comment: Homework? You have the values of a and b so you can work out which if clauses are true and hence what happens to z1. if you want a simplified version for all a/b then I'm not sure why you give values...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first condition is the same as the second, the third is the negation of the others, so we have

```
if (a ^ b) {
   z1 += 99 + 19  // = 118
} else {
   z1 += 118
}
```

We can shorten that again, whatever a or b is, z1 is augmented by 118, so we just have

```
z1 += 118
```

Comment: Gosh ! Didn't saw that one coming !

Comment: the code should do the same with any a,b,c given, so the first and the second condition would not be the same?

Comment: Make a truth table if you don't believe me, the two conditions are the same whatever a or b are...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to figure out things like this in future then you might want to try writing a table (I think its called a truth table, but some of the more mathematically minded here may correct me) showing all possible inputs and their respective outcomes. Once you've written the table you should be able to quickly identify the *overall* logic and possibly simplify it.

For the above a table might look like this;

```
  a  |  b  |  z1
------------------
  t  |  t  |
  t  |  f  |
  f  |  t  |
  f  |  f  |
```

Go through each row and write the effects of z1 in the column. This should allow you to easily determine what's going on and how to shorten it, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ( a && ! b) || ( ! a && b) ) {
}
```

you can use

```
if ( a!=b) {
}
```

---

```
if ( ( a && b) || ( ! a && ! b) ) {}
```

you can use

```
if(a==b){}
```

---

```
if (a ^ b) {}
```

is ok in its place